# Kotlin flows merge triggers infinite loop

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-room

I'm building a native android app using Room for local persistence and Firebase to exploit multi-devices sync. The app manages a list of notes.

Room is the primary data source, and Firebase is the secondary data source that shoudl sync data across devices and platforms.

I have already implemented all needed operations from both Room and Firebase: fetch, add, update, delete. All is working great.

Now I need to define the rules and logic for how to sync data between Room and Firebase when the user is logged in.

When the app starts I modified the "getNotes()" function from this:

```
override fun getNotes(): Flow<List<Note>> {
    return dao.getNotes()
}
```

to this:

```
   override fun getNotes(): Flow<List<Note>> {
    return flowOf(dao.getNotes(), getRemoteNotes()).flattenMerge().combine(
        dao.getNotes()
    ) { remoteNotes, localNotes ->
        mergeNotes(remoteNotes, localNotes)     
    }.flatMapLatest {
        it
    }
}
```

where "getRemoteNotes()" is:

```
private fun getRemoteNotes(): Flow<List<Note>> = flow {
    try {
        val uid = authenticationManager.getUId()

        val querySnapshot = remoteGeneralCollection
            .document("${uid}")
            .collection(Constants.FIRESTORE_USER_BACKUP_COLLECTION)
            .get()
            .await()

        val notesRemoteList = querySnapshot.documents.map {
            val noteId = it["id"] as Long
            val noteTitle = it["title"] as String
            val noteContent = it["content"] as String
            val noteTimestamp = it["timestamp"] as Long
            Note(
                title = noteTitle,
                content = noteContent,
                timestamp = noteTimestamp,
                id = noteId.toInt()
            )
        }

        emit(notesRemoteList)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

and mergeNotes() this:

```
    private fun mergeNotes(remoteNotes: List<Note>, localNotes: List<Note>): Flow<List<Note>> = flow {
        val localNotesMap = localNotes.associateBy { it.id }
        val remoteNotesMap = remoteNotes.associateBy { it.id }

        val mergedNotes = remoteNotes.map { remoteNote ->
            val localNote = localNotesMap[remoteNote.id]

            if (localNote != null) {
                val mostRecentNote = if (remoteNote.timestamp > localNote.timestamp) remoteNote else localNote

                if (mostRecentNote == remoteNote) {
                        updateLocalNote(mostRecentNote)
                }
                mostRecentNote
            } else {
                    insertNote(remoteNote)
                remoteNote
            }
        }
        emit(mergedNotes)
    }
```

The problem is that the mergeNotes() is called continuosly in a infinite loop, and the comparison "mostRecentNote == remoteNote" triggers the continuos update even if the notes hasn't changed.

I'm not sure that the flows management in the "getNotes" function is correct, but I haven't found any other solution to merge 2 flows from local and remote.

I would like to understand why with this implementation triggers an infinite loop of mergeNotes calls. I also tried using *.distinctUntilChanged()* in various points of the flow collections but doesn't work.

Comment: `return flowOf(dao.getNotes(), getRemoteNotes()).flattenMerge().combine(dao.getNotes())` pretty surely is incorrect: you merge `dao.getNotes()` with itself

Comment: @m.reiter I have already tried with `return dao.getNotes().combine(
            getRemoteNotes() ) { localNotes, remoteNotes ->
            mergeNotes(localNotes, remoteNotes)}` and the result is always an infinite loop. But even in this case I don't understand why

Comment: Why would you use Room for local cache since Firestore already provides an [offline mechanism](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline)? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo offline mechanism provided by Firestore is intended only for short offline periods and it is not the best solution for a offline-first app where the sync between local and remote data can be not so frequent. I don't know how users will use the app.

Answer (score 0):

The code is stuck in a loop because the mergeNotes() function is making something like a copy that triggers itself each time it's used. You can update the merge function to return the merged list of notes synchronously as a List and doesn't emit a Flow.

suspend fun mergeNotes(remoteNotes: List, localNotes: List): List {
val localNotesMap = localNotes.associateBy { it.id }
val remoteNotesMap = remoteNotes.associateBy { it.id }

```
val mergedNotes = remoteNotes.map { remoteNote ->
    val localNote = localNotesMap[remoteNote.id]

    if (localNote != null) {
        val mostRecentNote = if (remoteNote.timestamp > localNote.timestamp) remoteNote else localNote

        if (mostRecentNote == remoteNote) {
            updateLocalNote(mostRecentNote)
        }
        mostRecentNote
    } else {
        insertNote(remoteNote)
        remoteNote
    }
}

return mergedNotes
```

}

the updated code

Comment: thanks for your help. Unfortunately I have already tried this option without success. I think the problem must be in the way I merge the 2 flows.